# Пропали файлы после обновления системы

Tags: linux

Обновил убунту, думал просто докачает файлы и все как всегда.Потом понял что обновление полностью всей системы. Ноутбук обновился и перезагрузился, но все файлы пропали

Comment: Дополнение, возможно их как то востановить ?

Comment: Какие **все** файлы пропали? На компьютере не осталось ни одного файла?

Comment: На Linux, (насколько я знаю), нужно делать кое-что чтобы файлы сохранились. Просто Линукс, чаще всего для безопасности и  полноценной работы новой ОС стирает все на жестком диске и устанавливает новую версию дистрибутива на чистый диск (по крайней мере, при работе с Peppermint у меня такое было). Есть даже специальная программа для создания отдельного места на жестком диске, которое система не стирает. Насчет вопроса по восстановлению, это надо в интернете искать отдельно.  Если укажите версию дистрибутива (с какой на какую, название системы), может, смогу помочь

Comment: Статья про восстановление файлов: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Не все файлы, имеется ввиду только пользовательские  файлы

Answer (score 0):

> все файлы пропали

Насколько я понимаю ситуацию, папка */home* у Вас была в том же разделе, что и корень файловой системы. Поэтому, когда (при обновлении) Вы разрешили отформатировать корневую ФС, это привело к тому, что */home* тоже был уничтожен.

Никогда так не делайте!!!  Всегда, выделяйте отдельный(!) раздел под каталог */home*. Тогда, при любых престановках и обновлениях ОС, с Вашими файлами не случится ничего. Пример:

```
$ mount
. . .
/dev/sda7 on / type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
. . .
/dev/sda8 on /home type ext3 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Т.е. корневая ФС распологается на */dev/sda7*, а домашняя - на */dev/sda8*. Форматирование корня при перестановке ОС никак не затрагивает */home*.